# Is it okay to omit the space after a comma in square bracket references, e.g. "[45,46,47,64]" in a research paper

Tags: commas, spacing

Should you still apply the rule that there is a space after the comma, or is it an accepted practice to omit the space in this case?

Comment: What citation style does your discipline use? The syntactic conventions and rules vary among them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is strictly a style manual question.

Check with the publisher of your paper. If it's a university (your MS thesis or PhD dissertation), you'll have to follow the university's style rules. If it's an academic journal, it'll either dictate a standard style manual, like the *CBE* or *APA*, or else the publisher's style manual. You'll have to follow the style manual's rules, not your gut or anyone else's advice, about this.

Answer (score 0):

The user21497's answer is technically correct, but I'm not aware of any style manual that would allow skipping a space after comma. 
If you list numbers, then skipping spaces is especially problematic because in some European countries comma is used in place of the decimal point; i.e. in Germany or Russia 1,5 means 1.5 as in "one point five."

Comment: References are integral. A reference number will not have fractional parts. There is no risk of ambiguity.

Comment: Some weird guy may have references like [5.1] and [5.2] for the two editions of [5] ???